# Why jdbc driver is not found from generated jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, maven, jdbc

I have a JAVA SE project that works fine. The problem arises when I try to use it externally as a jar.

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen. My JAVA SE project, as you can see in my pom, uses JDBC4.2. [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) states:

> "In previous versions of JDBC, to obtain a connection, you first had
>   to initialize your JDBC driver by calling the method Class.forName."

Moreover:

> Any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your class path are
>   automatically loaded. (However, you must manually load any drivers
>   prior to JDBC 4.0 with the method Class.forName.)

For this reason, I do not need to write Class.forname(...) in DBConnection class (see below).

When I use DBConnection in my project, it works properly, but, if I create a jar and try to import it in another project, I get the following exception: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbName". The following are the steps I do to create the jar:

1. mvn clean install
2. create new java project (TestProject) in a new empty clean workspace
3. create a test class with main
4. call a class that uses DBConnection from main
5. I have no compilation problem (all the classes from the jar are loaded correctly)
6. When I run the main, "getConnection" of my DBConnection class throws the following exception: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbName"
7. **If** I right click on TestProject-> configure -> convert to maven project, then add postgres driver dependency, **it all works fine!!!**.

Shouldn't the PostgreSQL driver already be present in my jar? Why should I add it in the dependencies of the user project?

The following is the code of the class DBConnection:

```
package generic.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DBConnection {

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "db";
    private static final String URL = "url";
    private static final String USER = "user";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";

    private static Connection conn;

    private DBConnection(){

    }

    public static synchronized Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

        if(DBConnection.conn == null || DBConnection.conn.isClosed()){
            Properties props = PropertiesReader.readPropertyFile(FILE_NAME);

            String url = props.getProperty(URL);
            String user = props.getProperty(USER);
            String password = props.getProperty(PASSWORD);

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            DBConnection.conn = conn;
        }

        return DBConnection.conn;
    }

}
```

The following is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactid</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behaviour does not repackage dependend libraries into the created artifacts. Usually external libraries will not changed as often as your software does, and will be deployed to an application server.

With microservices e.g. spring-boot this has changed and you can deploy a single .jar file including all dependencies (even tomcat is included).

You have two options:

- Put all libraries in a lib-folder and add it to the classpath.
- [Create a fat jar](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/)

Comment: "Usually external libraries will not changed as often as your software does, and will be deployed to an application server". In JAVA EE envorinment, when I have many projects, It often occurs that a project depends on others, but there are not such dependency problems (as in this situation). Is it because the application server downloads dependencies on behalf of them?

Comment: No in JEE e.g. JBoss you can install third party libraries only once. (With the option to update to get security fixes or new features) The .ear and .war packages can also include a bunch of 3rd party libraries in WEB-INF/lib. But .jar cannot include other jar-files this can only be achieved by repackaging (combine all class files of all dependencies into a new jar) as a fat jar.

Comment: Creating fat jars should be done carefully when involving JDBC drivers. If your application needs multiple drivers, you need to be sure the `/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file is correctly merged.